# Variable not being recognized as variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, syntax

Would someone be able to tell me where I am wrong in the following code? For some reason the first 'contact' in 'contact.name' is not seen a variable.

```
var newContact = new Contact({
    contact.name = req.body.name, 
    contact.email = req.body.email, 
    contact.number = req.body.number
});
```

Comment: where did you declare `contact` ?

Comment: Is contact a class? or a new variable?

Comment: And what is `contactSchema`?

Comment: @BaneetGrover You didn't add the `contactSchema`

Comment: @Cristy the contactSchema is added in the contacts.js file so it carries through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to do something like this?

```
var newContact = new Contact({
    contact: {
        name: req.body.name, 
        email: req.body.email,
        number: req.body.number
    }
});
```

We need to know more about the `Contact` class constructor and its parameters in order to make sure that the passed arguments are in the correct form.

It would actually make more sense to have the arguments like this:

```
var newContact = new Contact({
        name: req.body.name, 
        email: req.body.email,
        number: req.body.number
});
```

Comment: What error do you get? The problem is you are using a `contact` variable that is never declared.

Comment: Turns out this was the correct way to do it. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: plus1 to understand the question and figure out issue in code.